# Using 3.3 and 2.7 Python versions simultaneously in the same script - Using instruction in "Learning Python" by M. Lutz

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, version

I am reading the Learning Python book of Mark Lutz and I am trying to follow his examples on how to run both versions of Python (2.7 and 3.3).

I am running Windows 10 and have installed Python via Anaconda 3 and I am using it interactively primarily within Jupyter Notebooks.  In some cases I would like to merge in the same Jupyter Notebook code from both versions and if I have understood well Mark's writings this should be possible (although he does not refer explicitly to Jupyter Notebooks at all in the book I am reading.)

Specifically I am following Mark's instructions and examples in Appendix B of his book which is dedicated to this issue.

So I have created two .py files with the following content:

**what.py**

```
#!python3
import sys
print(sys.version.split()[0])
```

**what2.py**

```
#!python2
import sys
print(sys.version.split()[0])
```

In page 1444 of his book Mark states:

> As mentioned, version switches on command lines can be used to select
>   a Python version if one isn’t present in the file. You run a py or pyw
>   command line to pass them a switch this way, instead of relying on
>   filename associations in the registry, and instead of (or in addition
>   to) giving versions in #! lines in files. In the following, we modify
>   our script so that it has no #! directive:

```
C:\code> py −3 what.py # Run per command-line switch
3.3.0 
C:\code> py −2 what.py # Ditto: latest 2.X installed
2.7.3
```

However, when I run these commands I get an exception:

```
D:\Mint_ns>py -2 what.py
'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Mint_ns>python what2.py
3.6.2

D:\Mint_ns>python what.py
3.6.2
```

I searched in my C drive where the programs are installed but I could not locate py.exe or pyw.exe:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a PYTHON environment variable, but I can't see the whole definition of your PATH environment variable. That error means that your py command or python is not in the PATH.
Start trying to fix it